# Как вывести вертикальный текст на RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

разбираю пример с вертикальным TextView http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/verticaltextview.php

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ru.alexanderklimov.test.RotateTextView
        android:id="@+id/rotateTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все работает на LinearLayout, но мне нужен более сложный макет где используется RelativeLayout и тут получаю обрезание текста, как исправить?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ru.alexanderklimov.test.RotateTextView
        android:id="@+id/rotateTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну если на LinearLayout работает, то не пробовал поместить свой TextView в LinearLayout и так работать?

Comment: @NikotinN, пробовал, но работает только при LineaLayout.layout_width/height = math_parent или fill_parent, в результате деформируется верхний RelativeLayout. При LinearLayout.layout_width = wrap_content не работает

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться решением из данного [ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/726954)

Comment: @IvanVovk, спасибо, но оно точно совпадает с моим вариантом. Вынес подложку в RelativeLayout, а текст во внутреннем LinearLayout оставил. Кривое решение, но работает.